# Retrieve image from sql database and post it in a table

Tags: php, html, sql

I have added to an sql database some images and some other data using php. Now I want to retrieve them and post them to a table using php.The table will have multiple rows. I want on the first cell of the row the image and on the next a list of data.The table will have multiple rows.
I have managed to post the data correctly but not the image. I have searched a few post and tried some methods but no solution. Can you assist me?
I post the code next:

```
<?php

session_start();

$pagetitle="Fleet";
include_once('head.php');
include_once('navbar.php');
connectDB();
?>
</head>

<?php 
 //DISPLAY A LIST OF ALL Files
$sql = "select * from Fleet";
$result = mysqli_query($mydb, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($mydb));
?>
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<?php
while($Fleet=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo"<tr>";

    echo "<td><img src='images/".$row['image']."'></td>";
    echo"<td><ul><li><b>".$Fleet['Name']."</li>";
    echo"<li>".$Fleet['AircraftRange']."</li>";
    echo"<li>".$Fleet['Length']."</li>";
    echo"<li>".$Fleet['Height']."</li>";
    echo"<li>".$Fleet['WingSpan']."</li>";
    echo"<li>".$Fleet['Passengers']."</li>";
    echo"<li>".$Fleet['Payload']."</li></td>";
    echo"</tr>";



}
?>




<?php

include_once('footer.php');
include_once('scripts.php');
?>
```

Comment: guess is the image path is broken, check the console to see if the image request is sent correctly

Comment: You are right. I got the following message in the console

Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "the folder address".
Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: you're echoing the image OUTSIDE of your table cells/rows, which places it in illegal territory as far as html is concernted, plus are missing the opening `<` on the img tag anyways.

Comment: deleted the extra one that echoed the picture outside of the table but still getting the message in the console I stated above

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
$row['image'];
```

Should be:

```
$Fleet['image'];
```

Comment: I corrected this value but still I get a broken image symbol instead of the image and the console says ''Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)''

Comment: Then your image probably isn't in the path linked to. Please show the HTML after execution of PHP-script again. Also, post the structure of sql-table, please.